# How to write a sqlite query to get specific data?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I want to get the first name, middle name and last name of a student whose userid is used for login. I have written this particular piece of code but it stops my application.

I have used both the ways like database.query() and .rawquery() also.

```
    Cursor studentData(String userId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(studentTable, new String[] { "First_Name", "Middle_Name", "Last_Name"}, "User_ID=?", new String[] { userId }, null, null, null, null);
//        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select First_Name, Middle_Name, Last_Name from Student_Table where User_ID =?", new String[]{userId});
        String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("First_Name"));
        db.close();
        return cursor;
    }
```

I should get whole name in the string.

Comment: can you share the error that is shown when your application is stopped? it can shed some light into where your code ( or something else ) is going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues.

1. Attempting to use `String data = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("First_Name"));`, 
   will result in an error because you have not **moved** the cursor beyond **BEFORE THE FIRST ROW** and the attempt to access the row **-1** will result in an exception (the likely issue you have encountered).

   - you can use various move??? methods e.g. moveToFirst, moveToNext (the 2 most common), moveToLast, moveToPosition.
   - Most of the Cursor move??? methods return true if the move could be made, else false.
2. You CANNOT close the database and then access the Cursor *(this would happen if the issue above was resolved)*

   - The Cursor buffers rows and then ONLY when required.
   - That is The Cursor is when returned from the query method (or rawQuery) at a position of **BEFORE THE FIRST ROW** (-1), it's only when an attempt is made to move through the Cursor that the CursorWindow (the buffer) is filled (getCount() included) and the actual data obtained. So the database MUST be open.

**If you want a single String, the full name, then you could use** :-

```
String studentData(String userId) { //<<<<<<<<<< returns the string rather than the Cursor
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String rv = "NO NAME FOUND"; //<<<<<<<<<< value returned if no row is located
    Cursor cursor = db.query(studentTable, new String[] { "First_Name", "Middle_Name", "Last_Name"}, "User_ID=?", new String[] { userId }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.modeToFirst()) {
        String rv = 
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("First_Name")) +
            " " +
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Middle_Name")) +
            " " +
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Last_Name"));
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< should close all cursors when done with them
    db.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< not required but would result in an exception if returning a Cursor
    return rv;
}
```

**Or alternately :-**

```
String studentData(String userId) { //<<<<<<<<<< returns the string rather than the Cursor
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String rv = "NO NAME FOUND"; //<<<<<<<<<< value returned if no row is located
    Cursor cursor = db.query(studentTable, new String[] { "First_Name"||" "||"Middle_Name"||" "||"Last_Name" AS fullname}, "User_ID=?", new String[] { userId }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.modeToFirst()) {
        String rv = 
            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("fullname"));
    }
    cursor.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< should close all cursors when done with them
    db.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< not required but would result in an exception if returning a Cursor
    return rv;
}
```

- the underlying query being `SELECT First_Name||" "||Middle_Name||" "||LastName AS fullname FROM student_table;` so you concatenate the names as part of the query which returns just one dynamically created column named **fullname**.

Comment: Thank you so much. You have cleared all my doubts about fetching data from cursor.